# A combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I asked this question in math overflow, but I didn't get a satisfied answer. 
So I ask here again. Given two positive integers $k,n$, let $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq k,1\leq c\leq n}$ be a sequence of non-negative integers satisfy $\sum\limits_{1\leq r\leq k\\1\leq c\leq n}rm_{r}(c)=k$. And suppose $\chi(1),\chi(2),\dots,\chi(n)$ be $n$ variables. Then I believe the following identity should hold:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\sum\limits_{1\leq r\leq k,1\leq c\leq n}rm_{r}(c)=k}\prod_{1\leq c\leq n}\chi(c)^{\sum\limits_{r}m_{r}(c)}\sharp\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq k,1\leq c\leq n}=(\sum\limits_{1\leq c\leq n}\chi(c))(\sum\limits_{1\leq c\leq n}\chi(c)+n)\dots(\sum\limits_{1\leq c\leq n}\chi(c)+(k-1)n)
\end{equation}
where for each sequence $\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq k,1\leq c\leq n}$ we define  $\sharp\{m_{r}(c)\}_{1\leq r\leq k,1\leq c\leq n}=\frac{n^{k}k!}{\prod\limits_{c,r}((nr)^{m_{r}(c)}m_{r}(c)!)}$.
But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The right hand side looks like a rising factorial when you factor out the $n$'s and do $X =\sum \chi (c)$. So in the left might be useful to look at Stirling numbers of the first kind. Check formula 55 on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1585.pdf

Comment: @Phicar Hi, thank you so much! This is very inspiring. I think I know how to prove it now.

Comment: You are welcome. Let us know if you solve it.